# No Broadcasts sent when changing Bluetooth discoverability

Tags: android, bluetooth

currently I`m trying to set up an application to let two devices communicate via Bluetooth.

I have a screen showing a single `Button`. Clicking on this button shall make the device discoverable and disable the button. When the device is no longer discoverable, the button shall be enabled again.

Like suggested in the [Dev Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html#DiscoveringDevices) I register a `BroadcastReceiver` to be **notified when discoverability ends**.

***The Problem:***

Sometimes, I **don't receive any broadcast** when device is no longer discoverable. On the other hand, I usually get 2 broadcasts sent when entering discoverability. Discoverability works fine, proved by LogCat and devices seeing my Phone (HTC Desire HD) for 120 seconds.

This is a record from LogCat showing 2 broadcasts being received immediately after beginning discoverability:

```
03-25 23:01:47.557: INFO/System.out(16905): --------broadcast received-------------
03-25 23:01:47.557: DEBUG/MuliplayerServerActivity(16905): current scan mode: 21
03-25 23:01:47.557: DEBUG/MuliplayerServerActivity(16905): previous scan mode: 23
03-25 23:01:47.557: INFO/System.out(16905): --------broadcast received-------------
03-25 23:01:47.557: DEBUG/MuliplayerServerActivity(16905): current scan mode: 23
03-25 23:01:47.557: DEBUG/MuliplayerServerActivity(16905): previous scan mode: 21
```

My code starting the discoverability is the following:

```
private void becomeVisible() {

    Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(
            BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
    startActivityForResult(discoverableIntent,
            CODE_REQUEST_MAKE_DISCOVERABLE);

}
```

My `BroadcastReceiver`looks like this:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver discoverableModeChangedReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        System.out.println("--------broadcast received-------------");
        int scanMode = intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_SCAN_MODE,
                0);
        int scanModePrevious = intent.getIntExtra(
                BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_PREVIOUS_SCAN_MODE, 0);
        Log.d(TAG, "current scan mode: " + scanMode);
        Log.d(TAG, "previous scan mode: " + scanModePrevious);

        if (scanMode == BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE) {
            // show button
            findViewById(R.id.btn_become_visible).setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            // hide button
            findViewById(R.id.btn_become_visible).setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You must  register action first:

```
IntentFilter intent = new IntentFilter();
intent.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
intent.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);
intent.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_SCAN_MODE_CHANGED); 
registerReceiver(discoverableModeChangedReceiver, intent);
```

Comment: the receivers are registered. do you know whether it might be a problem only on my phone (desire hd)?